# How do I create a new attribute in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Hi I'm new in ruby and rails and I want to create a new attribute email for the model Account. 
Down below is the test for my new attribute. The test is a copy of the name attribute test but i figured that they will be working in a similar way.

```
it "should have a email field" do
  @account.email = "email"
  @account = save_and_reload(@account)
  @account.email.should == "email"
end
```

The only thing I've done to make the test pass is to create a email attribute in the account model. And I have also manually inserted a new column email in the database account table.

Here is part of the account model code where I've inserted the email attribute:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :logo, :account_preference_attributes,:email
```

When i run the test I get the error NoMethodError in 'Account should have a email field'

```
undefined method `email=' for #<Account:0xb6468ca8>
```

So how do I create a new attribute in the model?

Comment: Is email listed in your db/schema.rb file as part of the account model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a migration to add email column into the table and run rake db:migrate

> ```
> class AddSsl < ActiveRecord::Migration
>  def self.up
>    add_column :accounts, :email, :string
>  end
>
>  def self.down
>    remove_column :accounts,:email
>  end 
> end
> ```

Also remove the email column from the table that you have manually added.

Comment: I removed the column from the database that I added manually. I created a new file in the migration folder with the code above. I ran rake db:migrate but in the end nothing happened. Is there something I have forgotten to do?

Comment: Is that migration adds email column to your table? 
try to rolled your migration to zero and run it again. Also, mention the RAILS_ENV=test while running the migration

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing `attr_accessible` with `attr_accessor`. The former is how Rails protects attributes from mass-assignment, while the latter is a Ruby directive which creates reader and writer methods for instance variables.

If you just want to use an instance variable in your model, use `attr_accessor`. If you want to create a persistent attribute, where the value gets stored to a column in the table, create a migration and add the column there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem occurs because you've only changed it on your development database, tests run on a seperate database that gets reset everytime you run your testsuite.

Make a [migration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) and then run the following command to migrate your test environment, or leave out the RAILS_ENV part to just do it for development:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```